# Permutation/Combination of x,y and z moves

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

First of all, I am not quite sure but I think the problem asks for a permutation/combination of 13 elements over the {*x*, *y*, *z*} set.

Here is the problem: How many ways are there for a spaceship to travel in a 3-D space from the origin (0,0,0) to the point (2,4,7) by taking 13 steps, one at a time, where a step moves one unit in the positive *x*, *y* or *z* direction? Moving in the negative *x*, *y* or *z* direction is prohibited.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Where does 12 come from?

Comment: **Hint**: How many $x$-steps? $y$-steps? $z$-steps? How many ways of permuting these steps?

Comment: 12 was a typo. Fixed now. Excuse me, I don't understand what you mean with your second question. Could you, please, be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are thirteen available steps, 2 of which must change $x$, $4$ of which must change $y$ and $7$ of which must change $z$. There are $\binom{13}{2}$ ways to choose the $x$-changing steps, $\binom{11}{4}$ ways to choose the y steps from the remaining steps, and then you're done since the remaining steps are automatically z-changing steps. So the final anaswer is $\binom{13}{2}\binom{11}{4}$.

Comment: Now I get it. I tried to approach it analogically starting with _y_, then _z_, and leaving _x_ for the end. I got the same answer $\binom{13}{4} \binom{9}{7} = 25740$. Thank you!

Comment: I find it easier with the multinomial $\dfrac{13!}{2!\, 4!\,7!} =25740$

Comment: Thanks! Indeed it is a very good alternative.

Comment: A good way of understanding the multinomial, incidentally: start by labeling all your steps uniquely as $x_a$, $x_b$, $y_a$, $y_b$, etc; then there are $13$! permutations of these labeled objects.  Now 'unlabel' the two $x$ steps, since they can't be distinguished from each other; this removes a factor of $2!$ from the result.  Similarly, unlabeling the four $y$ steps removes a factor of $4!$ from the result, and unlabeling the seven $z$ steps removes a factor of $7!$ from the result, leaving you with that multinomial.